# Wifi Network is not detecting

Tags: networking, wifi, kali-linux, drivers, iwlwifi

I am using kali linux. version check by `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:    2021.1
Codename:   kali-rolling
```

I guess there is problem with network adpater.

output for  `ifconfig` is

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 8c:16:45:54:4c:ad  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 788  bytes 61140 (59.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 788  bytes 61140 (59.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.42.234  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
        inet6 fe80::a800:26ff:feb5:a336  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether aa:00:26:b5:a3:36  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 17845  bytes 17447803 (16.6 MiB)
        RX errors 4  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 4
        TX packets 17371  bytes 4356032 (4.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 16:c9:1c:51:c2:06  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

output for command `iwconfig` is

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          
usb0      no wireless extensions.
```

network card show by `lspci | grep Network`

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

I try to install driver for my network card. [github directory of driver](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce)
after completing prerequisite when I run

```
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

output is

```
About to run dkms install steps...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8821ce-v5.5.2_34066.20200325
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
Module rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325 already built for kernel 5.10.0-kali7-amd64/4
Module rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325 already installed on kernel 5.10.0-kali7-amd64/x86_64
Finished running dkms install steps.
```

which means I had preinstalled driver but still, the wifi is not working.

any suggestion?

output for  `ip link show`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:16:45:54:4c:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:e7:51:18:90:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr b0:fc:36:32:7d:cb
4: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 92:52:11:d0:17:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 0):

You should "up" your wlan0.

```
wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:e7:51:18:90:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr b0:fc:36:32:7d:cb
```

Look at state that is DOWN.

```
sudo ip link set dev wlan0 up
```

Comment: after running  `sudo ip link set dev wlan0 up ` output is blank and  wlan0 is still down. @Istiak

Comment: actually no carrier means the card is administratively up (as seen with the first UP written) or it wouldn't display this piece of information.